# LinkAssemblies error in release mode build xamarin monodroid

Tags: .net, xamarin.android

I am getting "LinkAssemblies" error while building in release mode, however it is working fine in debug mode. Error is :

**Error 9 The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly. Xamarin.Android.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006: Reference to metadata item 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConditionalWeakTable`2' (defined in 'System.Reactive.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35') from 'System.Reactive.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' could not be resolved. at Xamarin.Android.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, String message, Object[] args) at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute() at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute() at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__20.MoveNext() C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets 955 5 QFeedback.Droid**

Can anyone please help me to solve this error?